# Basic Map And I am Stuck in FOR Loop

Tags: apex, class, collection

Here is my Map

```
Map<id,List<Custom_Report_2__c>> mapreports= new Map<id,List<Custom_Report_2__c> >();
for( Custom_Report_2__c  cr:cr1){
     mapreports.put(cr.Associated_Loan__c,new List<Custom_Report_2__c>());
     mapreports.get(cr.Associated_Loan__c).add(cr);
}
```

Even **mapreports** stores only one record where as there has to be 200 records :(
This list of Custom report has 200 records per id. 
when i try to get all the records thru for loop i get only i record per id with its list.

```
for(list<Custom_Report_2__c> ad : mapreports.values()){
     system.debug('a'+ad);
}
```

This for loops accepts only **`list <Custom_Report_2__c>`** 
how do i store all the values for the map returned.

Correct me if my declarations are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
Map<id,List<Custom_Report_2__c>> mapreports= new Map<id,List<Custom_Report_2__c> >();
for( Custom_Report_2__c  cr:cr1){
     //it will check if the Associated_Loan__c already exist in map or not. 
     // if not then put the first value into map as key and value
     if(!mapreports.containsKey(cr.Associated_Loan__c)){
        mapreports.put(cr.Associated_Loan__c,new List<Custom_Report_2__c>{cr});

     }
     else{//here since the Associated_Loan__c already exist then 
          //it will get the existing list of Custom_Report_2__c and add into the list
         mapreports.get(cr.Associated_Loan__c).add(cr);
     }
}
```

---

```
for(Id al:mapreports.keySet()){
      system.debug(al+'====key=====values=='+mapreports.get(al));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because each time you are initializing a new list inside your map, that overwrite your old vales.

So you need to keep track of your old value and if your map doesn't have the key then only you should initialize.

```
Map<id,List<Custom_Report_2__c>> mapreports= new Map<id,List<Custom_Report_2__c> >();
for( Custom_Report_2__c  cr:cr1){
     if(!mapreports.containsKey(cr.Associated_Loan__c)) //first check if key exisyt, if not add then only initialize
        mapreports.put(cr.Associated_Loan__c,new List<Custom_Report_2__c>);

     mapreports.get(cr.Associated_Loan__c).add(cr);  
}
```